# How to make an array with equal number of items depending on the number of items

Tags: python

The function gets two arguments, L is length of the list and 1..N - numbers are in the list.


I want to make a function that makes an array: it must be consist of length L and 1..N numbers,


Here are some examples:


If **array length = 10** and **numbers = 2**, than it has length 10 and numbers are in the list - 1..2

```
array = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

If **array length = 10** and **number = 3**, than it has length 10 and numbers are in the list - 1..3

```
array = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

If **array length = 10** and **numbers = 4**, than it has length 10 and numbers are in the list - 1..4

```
array = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

So the spaces between the number of items are nearly equal and distributed in the length provided.

Can someone help please :)

Comment: how would distribution look like for length 10 and number of items 7?

Comment: Where is the code you have written to attempt to solve this problem? What is the problem you have with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def func(L, N):
    ans = []

    while len(ans) != L:
        for i in range(N, 0, -1):
            ans.append(i)
            if len(ans) == L:
                break
    
    return sorted(ans)
```